# Is it possible to set useState with a variable?

Tags: react-native, variables, state

With a functional component using the react setState, is it possible to have a toggle function use argument variables to change a state?

```
 const WhateverScreen = props => {
   const [showPieView, setShowPieView] = useState(false);
   const [showPizzaView, setShowPizzaView] = useState(false);
   const [showBurgerView, setShowBurgerView] = useState(false);

  const toggleView = (value) => {
      const stateData = "show" + value;
      const setStateData = "setShow" + value;
      if(stateData === true) {
         setStateData(false);
       } else {
        setStateData(true)
       };
      };
```

Then down in render:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {toggleView("Pizza")}} >
     <Ionicons name="ios-information-circle" size={40} color={"green"} />
  </TouchableOpacity>

 {showPizzaView ?
      <View >
        <Text>I like Pizza!!!</Text>
        <Image source={require("../images/pizza.jpg")} style= {height: 100, width: 100}/>
      </View> : null}
 }
```

I can just write a bunch of functions for each Touchable element, but then DRY, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to access each function by name, you could add each dispatcher to an object:

```
// rest of code
const [showPieView, setShowPieView] = useState(false);
const [showPizzaView, setShowPizzaView] = useState(false);
const [showBurgerView, setShowBurgerView] = useState(false);

const setShowView = {
  setShowPieView: setShowPieView,
  setShowPizzaView: setShowPizzaView,
  setShowBurgerView: setShowBurgerView
};
// rest of code
```

Then your `setStateData` would be `const setStateData = setShowView["setShow" + value;]`, and the rest of your code would work as is (PS: I haven't tested this, mostly trying to illustrate the idea (^^,).